# Why can't I upgrade my origin armor or my infinity blade?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

I have obtained the Origin Armor (the armor the worker wears), but I can't seem to upgrade it, or my Infinity Blade. Both are Level 10. How can I upgrade them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade an item past level 10 you need to complete the "deathless" series of quests. Deathless quests appear after you have finished the main quest for the game at least once. They are essentially a "hardcore" version of the game where you lose all your current gear upon dying.

You can upgrade your items another 5 levels every time you beat all deathless quests.